# kill a process that has been started using ./xxxxxxxxxxxx.sh using pkill

Tags: process, pkill

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I run pycharm on remote desktop using ssh by:

`cd /home/user/Documents/pycharm-community-2016.3/bin/ && ./pycharm.sh`

I need to kill this process. For other process like firefox, I use the following:

```
pkill firefox
```

How do I kill the pycharm using `pkill` ?
Or is there any more elegant way to get this done ?

Comment: Have you read the `pkill` manual page? Particularly the bit about the `-f` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the route that worked for me.

---

Step 1: remote login

---

Step 2:
use
`top`
to get process id (`pid`) of process associated with pycharm.
The process is java.

---

Step 3: use `kill pid` to kill the process.